# RxJava2 how to join 2 Single List into one list

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have 2 different data sources that I want to combine.

```
val source1: Single<List<Type1>> = Single.fromCallable({
    api.getSource1()
})!!

val source2: Single<List<Type2>> = Single.fromCallable({
    api.getSource2()
})!!

//PS.
class Type0()
class Type1 : Type0()
class Type2 : Type0()
```

I want to join 2 sources and get

```
Single<List<Type0>>
```

so I could do further processing of the data, I think I should use .zip method, but I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `zipWith` operator works well here, as it lets you provide a `BiFunction` that describes how to combine the two `Single` instances (in this case, we just concatenate them with the [`plus` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html)):

```
val zipped: Single<List<Type0>> = source1.zipWith(source2, BiFunction { l1, l2 -> l1 + l2 })
```